# Can't register MvcMailer with Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, castle-windsor, mvcmailer

I'm trying to integrate [MvcMailer](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer) into an ASP.NET MVC 4 app.

I installed the package from NuGet and generated a mailer with the `Scaffold` command with no issues. I ended up with a new folder Mailers containing `UserMailer` and `IUserMailer`, and an `UserMailer` folder under `Views`.

Now, I want to send out an email each time a user registers. All operations concerning users are handled by my `AccountController`, so I just figured I would alter its constructor to accept an instance of `IUserMailer`.

Castle Windsor, though, complains. It says that component AccountController can't be created because it has a dependency on IUserMailer that's waiting to be satisfied.

I've tried to register it with

```
container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                .BasedOn<IUserMailer>()
                .LifestyleTransient());
```

but Windsor still throws the same exception.

I've even tried registering it with

```
container.Register(Component.For<IUserMailer>());
```

which changes the error to "IUserMailer is abstract. As such, it is not possible to instantiate it as implementation of service IUserMailer. Did you forget to proxy it?"

I can't figure out how to get this thing to work. Anyone can help?

[This comment](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/issues/35#issuecomment-7429490) says that MvcMailer is not compatible with Castle Windsor, which would be somewhat sad. If that is the case, is there a way to get around that?

This might well be a dumb question, I have practically no experience with Windsor.

Answer (score 1):

I've just got MVCMailer working with castle windsor 3.2

For my solution I have a separate IOC project with all my installers.  In my Core project which is shared across all projects I created an empty interface `IMailer`

```
public interface IMailer
{
}
```

Then after you scaffold up a mailer inherit `IMailer`

```
public interface IAccountMailer : IMailer
{
     ...
}
```

This should allow you to generically register all your mailers with castle windsor like so.

```
container.Register(
    Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("MyDllName")
        .BasedOn<IMailer>().WithService.FromInterface()
        .LifestylePerWebRequest()
        );
```

Then you can do something like this in your controller

```
public class EmailController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IAccountMailer accountMailer;

    public EmailController(IAccountMailer accountMailer)
    {
        this.accountMailer = accountMailer;
    }
}
```

And as long as you've got your castle windsor creating your MVC and API controllers it should be able to create your mailers.

Answer (score 1):

Thus far:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IUserMailer>().ImplementedBy<UserMailer>().Named("MailerService").LifeStyle.Transient);
```

...is working for me, although there are reports that occasionally you get a null reference exception (as if the WhateverMailer wasn't instantiated by the Windsor container). I haven't encountered this yet, but if I did, I would have to go away from the container goodness, plug my nose, and new the mailer up in the applicable controller. If you're testing said controller, from your linked reference:

> I reassign my controller's Mailer manually in my test's setup as such:
>
> Target = new Controller(...) { MailService = MailServiceMock.Object };

Although it appears @Neil has a [good solution as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16645691/9344).